# Service Fabric debug on Refresh application generates links to build folder Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, service-fabric-stateless

I have a Blazor webassembly asp.net core hosted app which must run on Service Fabric. I also must be able to debug it regardless of Service Fabric publish mode (e.g. 'Refresh application', 'Remove application')

At the moment it does not work with 'Refresh application' because that option generates a link to the build folder of the asp.net core host, which does not include the wwwroot generated by the published Blazor wasm application. That causes that the host can not find the pages. On 'Remove application' a new published application is created which contains everything that it needs to run properly.

Is there a way that I can get that wwwroot upon application refresh?